# Restore original visitor IP for static site on AWS S3 using Cloudflare

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-s3, cloudflare, x-forwarded-for

I've a static site on `S3`, with cloudflare as my DNS provider. The server logs are collected in an S3 bucket. However the visitor IP address in the log files points to cloudflare servers instead of the real visitor IP. I know how to restore original visitor IP with `real_ip_header` using a LAMP/LEMP stack on EC2. [Article](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170706-How-do-I-restore-original-visitor-IP-with-Nginx-)

How can I do the same (i.e. restore original visitor IP) with S3 + cloudflare. Is there a bucket policy that lets me map a custom header (e.g. CF-Connecting-IP) to visitor IP or can I customize the log format to include this header ?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to do this with S3 access logging. You'd probably need to run a web server if you need this level of information.